# How to unbrick phone when both recovery and system are abcent?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot, unbricking

I have Lenovo A328 phone, after trying to upgrade to cyanogen it has no system and no recovery, when turning it on there is only loading screen. ADB asks to authorize the phone, but no dialog appears on the phone's screen.

Comment: I hate to be the one to break it to you, but you sound like your phone is dead and buried. Does it have Fastboot?

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit wrong, it appeared that i had no system and no bootloader (through which I used to launch recovery). I held both volume buttons and sticked usb cable during this - and it helped.